# Power BI to call CRM process

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dynamics-crm, crm, powerapps

I have a Power BI report that is used to view some data from SQL Server. The user can make selections and the data is displayed on a table in the report. When the user makes a selection and clicks a button in Power BI, I want it to create data validation activities in CRM.

Is there any way I can send the data and call a CRM process to create data validation activities?

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Answer (score 0):

PowerBI is meant for data visualization, not for application development, but can be extended for some extent. PowerBI can have a button, it has some [default actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-buttons#select-the-action-for-a-button) for the button click which is not enough for your scenario.

Probably some hyperlink to trigger the MS Flow on each row or call the REST web api endpoint url to achieve what you want.

Simply you can create a Canvas PowerApp where you can do application logics & embed it in Power BI.

If you think embedding your Power BI report in Canvas app will make sense, that is also possible.