# How to call a CRM action from powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dynamics-crm

Need to call a **CRM Custom Action** with parameters from **Powerbi**
Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Can you outline your requirements a bit better, for example what CRM are you using, what sort of parameters, what have you tried etc. Please review the how to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @susritha any follow up questions?

Comment: @susrithap if my answer helped you, can you upvote/accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI is just a data visualization platform, not a replacement for app development.

When you want to do such things like clickable action in each row of PowerBI report list of records - maximum possibility is hyperlink (url). Unfortunately CRM Custom action is not url accessible, but that too you want with paramters. Forget it.

I have other ideas shared in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219004/7920473), like you can try Power Automate (MS Flow) or custom API to explore by url accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve your requirement with the help of Power Automate.

Steps -

1. Create new flow with Http Trigger
2. Invoke flow URL from power BI
3. Call custom action from flow

Please mark my answer verified if i were helpful